# Rails 4 - use cloudfront with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

I have an application which works already (in staging and prod) with S3.
Now we want it to work with cloudfront.

I figured out that from some reason I have paperclip definitions in two places:

**/confog/initializers/paperclip.rb:**

```
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging? || true
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
end
```

**/config/environments/staging.rb** and **/config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => s3_options[:bucket],
    :access_key_id => s3_options[:access_key_id],
    :secret_access_key => s3_options[:secret_access_key]
  }
}
```

(I load `s3_options` from **s3.yml** file which I have)

**First question** - is it necessary (or on the other hand - is it wrong) to have these two places with configuration?

With this configuration I get this:

```
> Profile.last.image.url
=> "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/images/000/000/001/original/someimage.jpg?1439912576"
```

**My goal:** 
Get cloundfront url instead of s3.

I tried several things:

1. Add to **paperclip.rb** this line:

   ```
   Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_alias]  = "xxxxx.cloudfront.net"
   ```

   (where `xxxxx` stands for the cloudfront hash).
   **Result:** nothing is changed.
2. Add to **paperclip.rb** this line:

   ```
   Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name]  = "xxxxx.cloudfront.net"
   ```

   (where `xxxxx` stands for the cloudfront hash).
   **Result:** paperclip concatenate the bucket name **before** it:

   ```
   > Profile.last.image.url
   => "https://mybucket.xxxxx.cloudfront.net/profiles/images/000/000/001/original/someimage.jpg?1439912576"
   ```
3. Disable configuration in **paperclip.rb** and add these lines to the environment config file (I tried it on **development.rb**):

   ```
   config.paperclip_defaults = {
          :
     :s3_credentials => {
        :
        :
       :url => "xxxxx.cloudfront.net",
       :s3_host_name => "xxxxx.cloudfront.net",
       :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
     }
   }
   ```

   **Result:** paperclip concatenate the bucket name **after** it:

   ```
   > Profile.last.image.url
   => "https://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/mybucket/profiles/images/000/000/001/original/someimage.jpg?1439912576"
   ```
4. As (3), but add these lines one level higher:

   ```
   config.paperclip_defaults = {
     :storage => :s3,
     :url => "xxxxx.cloudfront.net",
     :s3_host_name => "xxxxx.cloudfront.net",
     :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
     :s3_credentials => {
        :
        :
     }
   }
   ```

   **Result:** Same as (3).

Briefly, no matter what I put in `:s3_host_name`, **paperclip concatenate the bucket name in some place**.

Some idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It was easier than I thought.
Looks like paperclip uses `:url` either as a string or as a reference for a symbol which indicates how to construct the url.

In my **/config/environments/staging.rb** and **/config/environments/production.rb** files I have now:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :url => ':s3_alias_url',
  :s3_host_alias => "xxxxx.cloudfront.net",
  :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
  :s3_credentials => {
       :
       :
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver.  Your config worked perfectly for our CloudFront upgrade.

Comment: What's the difference between `url` and `s3_host_alias`?

Comment: So do you use `bucket` anymore?

Comment: @J  Yes, I do use buckets, but in S3.

Answer (score 2):

Ended using:

```
  amazon = AppConfiguration.for :amazon

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    url: ':s3_alias_url',
    s3_host_alias: amazon.cloudfront,
    path: '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
    s3_protocol: :https,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: amazon.s3_bucket_name,
      access_key_id: amazon.aws_access_key_id,
      secret_access_key: amazon.aws_secret_access_key
    }
  }
```

Alternative to AppConfiguration

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  url: ':s3_alias_url',
  s3_host_alias: ENV['AMAZON_CLOUDFRONT'],
  path: '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
  s3_protocol: :https,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['AMAZON_S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AMAZON_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AMAZON_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Important to say, don't use **Rails.application.secrets** here. It's not available when the config files are loading on rails **4.1.8** at least